# How to convert a floating-point type to an integer type without rounding in VB6

Tags: vb6

What is the recommended way to convert a floating point type to an integer type, truncating everything after the decimal point? CLng rounds, apparently, and the documentation for the = operator doesn't mention the subject.

Comment: you should look at the link I gave to the accepted answer.  Fix has a bug in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive numbers you would use

```
truncated = Int(value)
```

If used on negative numbers it would go down, i.e. -7.2 would become -8.

Answer (score 11):

Use`Fix` or `Int` depending on the treatment you wish for negative numbers.

Microsoft article [Q196652](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q196652) discusses rounding in incredible detail. Here is an excerpt

> The VB `Fix()` function is an example
>   of truncation. For example, `Fix(3.5)`
>   is `3`, and `Fix(-3.5)` is `-3`.
>
> The `Int()` function rounds down to
>   the highest integer less than the
>   value. Both `Int()` and `Fix()` act
>   the same way with positive numbers -
>   truncating - but give different
>   results for negative numbers:
>   `Int(-3.5)` gives `-4`.

Full disclosure: I referred to [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647762/automatic-type-conversion-in-visual-basic-6-0/647829#647829) by [elo80ka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76664/elo80ka)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137114/how-to-round-in-ms-access-vba/137177#137177) that Fix has a bug in it.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Thank you for your note. It happens I chose Int. Phew!

Answer (score 4):

see
[this](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18525)

Undocumented behavior of the CInt() function
The CInt() function rounds to the nearest integer value. In other words, CInt(2.4) returns 2, and CInt(2.6) returns 3.

This function exhibits an under-documented behavior when the fractional part is equal to 0.5. In this case, this function rounds down if the integer portion of the argument is even, but it rounds up if the integer portion is an odd number. For example, CInt(2.5) returns 2, but CInt(3.5) returns 4.

This behavior shouldn't be considered as a bug, because it helps not to introduce errors when doing statistical calculations. UPDATE: Matthew Wills let us know that this behavior is indeed documented in VB6's help file: When the fractional part is exactly 0.5, CInt and CLng always round it to the nearest even number. For example, 0.5 rounds to 0, and 1.5 rounds to 2. CInt and CLng differ from the **Fix and Int functions, which truncate**, rather than round, the fractional part of a number. Also, Fix and Int always return a value of the same type as is passed in.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137114/how-to-round-in-ms-access-vba/137177#137177) for more info.

Comment: @Lance Roberts, does that also apply to VB6, or only VBA?

Comment: I haven't fully tested all the options in VB6, though that's a good idea.  The concept of Banker's Rounding is the same.

Comment: "Fix and Int always return a value of the same type as is passed in." -- Not so e.g. `TypeName(Int(CStr(1)))` returns 'Double', `TypeName(Int(CBool(1)))` returns 'Integer'.