# How to reduce the decimal length

Tags: vb6

I want to reduce the decimal length

```
   text1.text = 2137.2198231578
```

From the above, i want to show only first 2 digit decimal number

Expected Output

```
text1.text = 2137.21
```

How to do this.

Comment: no, i don't want to round the value

Comment: See also the rounding functions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647762/automatic-type-conversion-in-visual-basic-6-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Format("2137.2198231578", "####.##")
```

Comment: This will round the value rather than truncating. The output value is `2137.22` but JetJack has requested `2137.21`

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post use `Format()` when I noticed p0rter comment.

```
Format(text1.text, "000.00")
```

I guess `Int()` will round down for you.

Been many years since I used VB6...

Comment: Is this a guess, or an answer? It seems a bit like a comment .. consider revising?

Answer (score 0):

This function should do what you want (inline comments should explain what is happening):

```
Private Function FormatDecimals(ByVal Number As Double, ByVal DecimalPlaces As Integer) As String
    Dim NumberString As String
    Dim DecimalLocation As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LeftHandSide As String
    Dim RightHandSide As String

    'convert the number to a string
    NumberString = CStr(Number)
    'find the decimal point
    DecimalLocation = InStr(1, NumberString, ".")

    'check to see if the decimal point was found
    If DecimalLocation = 0 Then
        'return the number if no decimal places required
        If DecimalPlaces = 0 Then
            FormatDecimals = NumberString
            Exit Function
        End If
        'not a floating point number so add on the required number of zeros
        NumberString = NumberString & "."
        For i = 0 To DecimalPlaces
            NumberString = NumberString & "0"
        Next
        FormatDecimals = NumberString
        Exit Function
    Else
        'decimal point found
        'split out the string based on the location of the decimal point
        LeftHandSide = Mid(NumberString, 1, DecimalLocation - 1)
        RightHandSide = Mid(NumberString, DecimalLocation + 1)
        'if we don't want any decimal places just return the left hand side
        If DecimalPlaces = 0 Then
            FormatDecimals = LeftHandSide
            Exit Function
        End If
        'make sure the right hand side if the required length
        Do Until Len(RightHandSide) >= DecimalPlaces
            RightHandSide = RightHandSide & "0"
        Loop
        'strip off any extra didgits that we dont want
        RightHandSide = Left(RightHandSide, DecimalPlaces)
        'return the new value
        FormatDecimals = LeftHandSide & "." & RightHandSide
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Debug.Print FormatDecimals(2137.2198231578, 2) 'outputs 2137.21
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fairly simple, but I must be missing something subtle here.  What about:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function Fmt2Places(ByVal Value As Double) As String
    Fmt2Places = Format$(Fix(Value * 100#) / 100#, "0.00")
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Text1.Text = Fmt2Places(2137.2198231578)
End Sub
```

This also works in locales where the decimal point character is a comma.