# VB6 Round(x,0) issue

Tags: vb6, rounding

Something was causing unexpected results on my company long ago, and I found this problem:

```
Dim k As Double
Dim r As Integer
k = 182.5
r = Round(k,0)
```

The result of r is 182, this caused problems on my company and now i have to fix it.

The thing is that i observed this:

```
Dim k As Double
Dim r As Integer
k = 186.5
r = Round(k,0)
```

r = 187

When the unities of the integer part of the double are bigger than five, Round does what i expect, but it doesn't for unities <=5.

How can i solve this problem? Is there another function to get the right rounding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647762/automatic-type-conversion-in-visual-basic-6-0

Comment: In this case I'll use `r=int(k+0.5)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called *bankers rounding* and attempts to distribute rounding up/down on .5 based on whether or not the nearest number is odd or even.

To round up on .5:

```
cint(format(182.5, "#0")) ''183
cint(format(186.5, "#0")) ''187
```

Comment: One should note, however, that Format$ converts the double into a String, from which it has to be converted back into an Int. This is very inefficient. Format (without the $ sign) is even worse, because it produces a Variant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, it is not so as you say.

```
k = 182.5
r = Round(k, 0)
```

will indeed produce 182, but

```
k = 186.5
r = Round(k, 0)
```

will produce 186, not 187 as you mention. Now,

```
k = 185.5
r = Round(k, 0)
```

will yield 186 as well. This is called [Banker's Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) and is the standard in VB6. The intention is to undo the bias of always rounding an exact middle up.

If you want to always round 0.5 up, use

```
k = 186.5
r = Int(k * 2 + 1) \ 2
```

If you want to always round 0.5 down, you can use something along the line of

```
k = 186.5
r = Int(k * 2 + 0.99) \ 2
```

Add as many 9s as there are significant digits after the decimal point.